# Code only works if I NSLog some values - but why?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nslog

I'm writing a simple [QR code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_Code) generator (just for fun and to learn some Obj-C), and I'm working on tracing the outline of connected "modules" (i.e. the black squares that make up a QR code). This is in order to have nicer vector output than simply making a bunch of rects for each module.

Long story short, my outline-tracing code works - BUT ONLY if I make sure to call NSLog in a specific place! If I remove the `NSLog`-call, the code loops! I'm literally doing nothing but logging. And it doesn't matter what I log; I just have to call NSLog or things break.

The tracing algorithm is simple enough: Go clockwise around the shape of connected modules. When you hit a corner, turn right until you're back to following the outline of the shape. Stop when you reach the starting point again. The shape can have two modules that share a corner-point. The tracing-loop will thus hit that point twice. This is expected, and the code handles it correctly - *if* I call `NSLog`.

Otherwise, the code will say that a certain point is a corner the first time it sees it, and *not* a corner the second time, which causes the tracing to loop around. Detecting if something's a corner-point is not dependent on anything except the x and the y coordinates of the point and an array of module objects - but neither the modules nor the array changes while the tracing is going on, so given the same x,y you should *always* get the same result. And it does – *if* I call `NSLog`.

Without `NSLog`, the coordinates – e.g. (10,9) – is corner on moment, and a moment later (10,9) is suddenly *not* a identified as a corner. But *with* an `NSLog`-call, (10,9) is correctly seen as a corner-point every time.

Again: I change absolutely nothing; I just log something - anything! And suddenly it works. It's like it's saying that 2 == 2 is true *or* false, unless I tell it to log 2 and 2, in which case 2 == 2 is always true, as it should be.

Here's the flaky code. It's hard to understand out of context, but there's *a lot* of context, so I hope this is enough. Everything is integers (no fuzzy floating point values).

```
do { // start going around the shape

    // If this isn't here or simply commented out, the code loops.
    NSLog(@"foobar"); // doesn't matter what I log - I just need to log something

    // Branch: Is current x,y a corner-point? This should
    // always return the same result given the same X and Y
    // values, but it only does if NSLog is there!
    if( [self cornerAtX:x Y:y] ) {

        // add the point to the path
        [path addPoint:NSMakePoint(x, y)];

        // rotate the direction clockwise, until
        // the direction is following the edge of the
        // the shape again.
        do {
            dt = dx;
            dx = -dy;
            dy = dt;
        } while( ![self boundaryFromX:x Y:y inDirectionX:dx Y:dy] );
    }

    // continue along direction
    x += dx;
    y += dy;

} while( !(sx == x && sy == y) ); // we're back to the start of the shape, so stop
```

If anyone can tell me why NSLog can make code work (or rather: Why *not* using NSLog makes working code break), I'd be happy to hear it! I hope someone can make sense of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure `cornerAtX:Y:` always returns something—i.e., that there's no code path that fails to return a value.

Otherwise, it may very well “return” whatever the last function you called returns, in which case calling `NSLog` (which doesn't return a value, but may ultimately call a function that does) causes it to “return” something different, which may always be something that's considered true.

The compiler should warn you if you fail to return a value from a function or method that you declared as doing so. You should listen to it. [Turn on all the warnings you can get away with and fix all of them.](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2009-11-07/warnings)

You should also turn on the static analyzer (also included in that post), as it, too, may tell you about this bug, and if it does, it will tell you step-by-step how it's happening.

Comment: Ahh! Thank you! I ran the static analyzer right away (I'm new to all this stuff, so I hadn't thought to do it before), and it showed a couple of uninitialized BOOLs in cornerAtX:Y:. Init'ing them to NO did the trick. I'd never have thought of that, since every other language I know just inits booleans to false/no. And I was to lazy to write " = NO;" a couple of times :)  Thank you again!

Comment: @Flambino: In C (and, therefore, in Objective-C), no local variable is initialized unless you initialize it. (Exception: Static variables, even local ones, *are* initialized to zero. Instance variables are, too.) The type doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, and I think I did know that, but habits die hard, so I simply declared the bools without init'ing them. Guess I've learned my lesson - literally.

Comment: @Flambino: For every new project, you should immediately set the static analyser to run every build.  (It's in the project build settings.)  It will catch a lot of issues the compiler won't find.

Comment: @Flambino, @JeremyP: The script that's linked from my blog post will turn on the static analyzer, the useful compiler warnings, and “Treat Warnings as Errors” (so you can't get away with leaving compiler warnings unfixed). That makes it just a single step to do to each project to set those things up in it.

Answer (score 2):

There's not much to go on here, but I'd guess that it's either an uninitialized variable or some sort of memory stomping.  NSLog probably uses both stack and heap memory, so it could affect those.

Comment: Err... ok, you lost me there with the memory stuff :)
As for the first part: I can't see what uninitialized variables there could be. None that I've declared anyway. And besides, it make no difference what I log, so as far as I know I'm – at most – creating an NSString literal and sending it to NSLog.

Comment: @Flambino: Not even that. String literals are created at compile time. All your `NSLog` statement does at run time is pass the string in.

Comment: So, it turns out you were right all along. I hope you don't mind I marked Peter Hosey's answer below as the solution, but it wasn't until I read his answer that I fully understood it all. But thank you!

Comment: @Peter Hosey: Good point - I'm a bit damaged from too many scripting languages where compile time (well, evaluation) and run time get mixed up :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing NSLog with some other meaningless operation? If that will also work then I suppose problem is linked to [self cornerAtX: x Y: y].
Another possibility is that the problem is time-related. NSLog takes time to execute, so if QR code is loaded in another thread you can see this kind of behavior.

Comment: I just tried simply adding some ints and things like that, and the code still looped. So it seems the issue may indeed be time-related. But I haven't done anything even remotely like threading. It's a complete straightforward do-loop plus some ints and bools. So I'm still at a loss to explain what's going on... it should be completely deterministic. I don't see how the loop can work at all, if anything changes anywhere...